# Python script to Grep strings from input file and output in csv format

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a python script to grep string from file and display output in csv file in below format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKL2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC8Ww.png)

Input file(result_EPFT_config_device) :

```
Hostname SIM-MPL-LTE-PE-RTR-134
loopback 22.13.7.34
lpts punt excessive-flow-trap
penalty-rate arp 10
penalty-rate icmp 50
penalty-rate igmp 50
penalty-rate ip 100
exclude interface Bundle-Ether6
exclude interface Bundle-Ether8
exclude interface Bundle-Ether15
exclude interface Bundle-Ether16
exclude interface Bundle-Ether53
exclude interface TenGigE0/0/1/1
exclude interface TenGigE0/1/1/0
exclude interface Bundle-Ether6.2
exclude interface Bundle-Ether6.4
exclude interface Bundle-Ether8.2
exclude interface Bundle-Ether8.4
exclude interface Bundle-Ether16.2
exclude interface Bundle-Ether16.4
exclude interface Bundle-Ether53.2
exclude interface TenGigE0/0/1/3.100
exclude interface TenGigE0/0/1/3.102
exclude interface TenGigE0/0/1/3.103
exclude interface TenGigE0/0/1/3.104
exclude interface TenGigE0/1/1/0.100
exclude interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
exclude interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/6
exclude interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/9
dampening.
non-subscriber-interfaces
report-threshold 10
```

Below is the python script i have prepared as of now. Only able to grep string and print it

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import os
import subprocess
import re
import csv

fh = open("result_EPFT_config_device", "r")
fh1 = open("testingAjay", "w+")
line = fh.readlines()
for lines in line:
        if re.search("(lpts punt excessive-flow-trap)", lines):
                m =  (lines.split(' '))
                print m[0], m[1], m[2]
        if re.search("(penalty-rate arp)", lines):
                n =  (lines.split(' '))
                print n[0], n[1], n[2]
        if re.search("(penalty-rate icmp)", lines):
                a =  (lines.split(' '))
                print a[0], a[1], a[2]
        if re.search("(penalty-rate igmp)", lines):
                b =  (lines.split(' '))
                print b[0], b[1], b[2]
        if re.search("(penalty-rate ip)", lines):
                c =  (lines.split(' '))
                print c[0], c[1], c[2]
        if re.search("(dampening)", lines):
                c =  (lines.split(' '))
                print c[0]
        if re.search("(non-subscriber-interfaces)", lines):
                c =  (lines.split('-'))
                print c[0], c[1], c[2]
        if re.search("(report-threshold 10)", lines):
                c =  (lines.split(' '))
                print c[0], c[1]
```

My script output :

```
lpts punt excessive-flow-trap
penalty-rate arp 10
penalty-rate icmp 50
penalty-rate igmp 50
penalty-rate ip 100
dampening.
non subscriber interfaces

report-threshold 10
```

Now here i want to put the output in csv file as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9VMw.png)

```
Hostname|loopback|lpts punt excessive-flow-trap|penalty-rate arp|penalty-rate icmp|penalty-rate igmp|penalty-rate ip|dampening|non-subscriber-interfaces|report-threshold
SIM-MPL-LTE-PE-RTR-134|1.1.1.1|yes|10|50|50|100|Yes|Yes|10
NDL-MPL-PE-RTR-195|2.2.2.2|No|No|No|20|50|NO|20Yes
```

As shown in above screenshot, column **lpt spunt excessive flow trap** has to mark as YES if its present in Input File else mark NO. Similar logic needs to apply for column **dampening** and **non subscriber interface** column

Could you please help me to achieve require output in csv format as shown above

Comment: Hey, mind if I answer in python3?

Comment: you should create list or dictionary for all data in row, fill it using your code, and write row in csv when you get next `Hostname`

Comment: it seems you could test it without regex - ie. `if lines.startswith('lpts punt excessive-flow-trap'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go! So as the comment above said you can just use "startswith" rather then regex to match the lines.

I have used python3 rather then python2 here.

If you run this in a directory using "python3 main.py" it will search the "inputs" subdirectory for all files to parse.

We then build a dictionary for each file with the relevant fields and load their values. We add these dictionaries to a list. At the end we just write the headers to the csv then loop through the rows and write values. You could probably write the rows while reading the files but I find separating parsing and output cleaner mentally.

I changed the ordering of your "for lines in line" to "for line in lines" as you want to loop through each line in the lines.

```
import os
import csv

def parseFile(fileName):

    # We are using a dictionary to store info for each file
    data = dict()

    # Set all Yes/Nos to NO by default
    data["lpts punt excessive-flow-trap"] = "NO"
    data["dampening"] = "NO"
    data["non-subscriber-interfaces"] = "NO"

    fh = open(fileName, "r")
    lines = fh.readlines()
    for line in lines:

        # We need this so we don't end up with newline characters in our CSV
        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        # We dont need regular expressions here as matching whole line
        # Do YES/NO first
        if line == "lpts punt excessive-flow-trap":
            data["lpts punt excessive-flow-trap"] = "YES"
            continue;

        if line == "dampening":
            data["dampening."] = "YES"
            continue;

        if line == "non-subscriber-interfaces":
            data["non-subscriber-interfaces"] = "YES"
            continue;

        # Now do the rest
        if line.startswith("Hostname"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["Hostname"] = splitted[1]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("loopback"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["loopback"] = splitted[1]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("penalty-rate arp"):
            print("ARP")
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["penalty-rate arp"] = splitted[2]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("penalty-rate icmp"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["penalty-rate icmp"] = splitted[2]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("penalty-rate igmp"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["penalty-rate igmp"] = splitted[2]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("penalty-rate ip"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["penalty-rate ip"] = splitted[2]
            continue;

        if line.startswith("report-threshold"):
            splitted = line.split(' ')
            data["report-threshold"] = splitted[1]
            continue;

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputsDirectory = "inputs"
    path = os.path.abspath(inputsDirectory)
    fileList = ["{}/{}".format(path,x) for x in os.listdir(inputsDirectory)]
    print(fileList)

    # Load Each File and Build Dictionary
    csvRows = []
    for file in fileList:
        newRow = parseFile(file)
        csvRows.append(newRow)

    print(csvRows)

    # Output CSV using dictionaries for each file
    outputFile = "output.csv"
    with open(outputFile, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["Hostname",
                      "loopback",
                      "lpts punt excessive-flow-trap",
                      "penalty-rate arp",
                      "penalty-rate icmp",
                      "penalty-rate igmp",
                      "penalty-rate ip",
                      "dampening",
                      "non-subscriber-interfaces",
                      "report-threshold"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for row in csvRows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @Researcher...thank you very much...that worked.
I jut replaced newline='' with wb

Comment: Awesome, I have updated the answer to remove that. I copy pasta'd some of that csv code and didn't see the newline override :)

Comment: @Researcher...can you please tell me ...how to do...if i have multiple input file and i want to generate multiple output file from these input files in another directory...Ex - Input File A.txt, B.txt, C.txt then i need same output file with another folder...A.csv, B.csv, C.csv